# How to Read Magstripe Data?

Tags: python, magnetic-cards

I'm looking to create a small magstripe reader for my company.

We wanted to do a fun little side project to access the main front door. Ideally we wanted to create a little box with an LCD screen that greets our employees when they swipe their company card. I have looked at devices on amazon and the such and they are way too big to store in a box.

How would I go about this? I would like something small that can read the magstripe data and then use a Raspberry Pi to check a local database to see if the card matches.

If you have any info on reading magstripe data that would be awesome! Thanks.

Comment: a lot of the magstripes are just "plug and play" and you can read them from a text file. 
if you store the staff id on the card and then you can use a python script to search the database for the staff name and display it on the LCD with a welcome message. 

you just need the mag stripe for the ID really everything else can be pulled from the database

Comment: @JeanCamargo We're mainly looking for a small reader. It seems you could purchase a magnetic head but how I would go about turning that into data? I'm not too familiar with that. The "plug and play" ones seem wayyy too big. Ideally the box should be an inch or less thick and less than 10 inches wide.